# How to Find and Replace using YQ in Shell script / Yaml?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, yaml, yq

I have around 200-300 yaml files lying around and What I am trying to achieve is to change only the image: option in few of my yaml files, I have a shell script which can get the required yaml files, and I just want to achieve changing the image: key only.

**Solution Tried:**

Used a tool [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) v4:

```
for i in ${deployment[@]}
 do
 yq eval '( select(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image |= "gcr.io/myrepo/mynginx:1.2.3"'  deployment-$i.yaml
done
```

What this command does is it achieves the desired result of changing the image, but it also appends the changes on the all the parts of deployment file which is for example at the end of every spec in the file:

```
        apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: portal-1
        spec:
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              component: portal-1
              role: ui
          replicas: 1
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                component: reactportal
                role: ui
            spec:
              containers:
                - name: portal
                  image: gcr.io/myrepo/mynginx:4.52 <<< Desired CHange Happens Here >>>
        ---
        
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Ingress
        metadata:
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "false"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com"
      name: portal-ingress
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: mydomain.com
          http:
            paths:
              - backend:
                  serviceName: portal-svc
                  servicePort: 80
                path: /(.*)
 template:                                                  <<<< THIS IS ALSO GETTING APPENDED >>>
        spec:
          containers:
            - image: gcr.io/myrepo/mynginx:1.2.3
```

How to achieve the desired result without appending the image on every part of the deployment file?

Comment: Please provide a [minmal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, you don't show the input YAML and also it does not seem to be relevant that you process multiple YAML files if the problem happens with each one, so it would be better to just show one stripped-down YAML input file where the problem happens, the actual and the desired output. Concerning the problem, it may help to close the two open parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) ?

I would do it with a fairly simple `bash` one-liner, using `sed`:

```
for i in {1..3}; do sed -i "s/image.*/image: mysql:latest/" deployment-$i.yaml; done
```

The above command searches for the string `"image"` followed by any other characters till the very end of the line (so it takes the whole string `image: "my-fancy-image-name"`) and replaces it with completely new string - in the above example the new string is `image: mysql:latest`.

The option `-i` or `--in-place` is used for editing files in place i.e. the original file is edited and saved with a new content.

The only asssumption is that you have a fixed naming convention for your deployment files i.e. the correct names for the above example are: `deployment-1.yaml`, `deployment-2.yaml` etc.

If you want to put your image name in double quotes as in your example, you can do it this way:

```
for i in {1..3}; do sed -i "s/image.*/image: \"gcr.io\/myrepo\/mynginx:1.2.3\"/" deployment-$i.yaml; done
```

As you can see, certain characters that have a special meaning for `sed` command like `"` or `/` have to be escaped with `\` character so they can be used in your replacement string.

Actually there is one more assumption when using the above script, namely that the `"image"` string occurs exactly once in your `Deployment`. If this is the case, you don't need to worry about adding `g` option for global replacement (every occurance of the searched string). The above examples will perform the replacement only on the first occurence of the `"image"` string, which should satisfy your requirements. If you have deployments with more than one container e.g. an init container or sidecar, most likely you wouldn't be interested in changing every `image` in such deployment to the same single value anyway.

Comment: Thank you mario, this is the easiest way to make this work. I wasn't sure if I could make this any smaller

Answer (score 3):

This should get you the expected result :

```
for i in ${deployment[@]}; do
  yq eval '.spec|=select(.selector.matchLabels.component=="portal-1")
                 .template.spec.containers[0].image =
                    "gcr.io/myrepo/mynginx:1.2.3"' deployment-$i.yaml
done
```